# Firebase, IN clause query and lists of datas

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, non-relational-database

In my opinion this is pretty obvious question when someone has to deal with a DB, so I don't know why I can't find anything about it.
I'm trying to design the **non-relational database** for my project. I have a list of products described by some info (e.g. the code, an image and a multi language description) and they are categorized in different ways. Here is a snap of the structure:

```
"products" : {
    "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfa" : {
      "code" : "IR3300000000",
      "schema" : "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/",
    },
    "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfb" : {
      "code" : "PJ0000000000",
      "schema" : "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/",
    }
  }

"it" : {
    "products" : {
      "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfa" : {
        "description" : "desc product IR330000000"
      },
      "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfb" : {
        "description" : "description product PJ00000 lorem ipsum"
      }
    }
  }
```

And below there are a couple of usages of the products, the real structure is much more complex, but probably it's enough to explain my problem:

```
"families" : {
    "family1" : {
        "products" : {
            "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfa" : true,
            "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfb" : true
        }
    },
    "family2" : {
        "products" : {
            "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfa" : true
        }
    }
}

"applications" : {
    "application_1" : {
        "products" : {
            "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfa" : true,
            "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfb" : true
        }
    },
    "application_1" : {
        "products" : {
            "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfa" : true,
        }
    }
}
```

Ok, now let's move to the client side!

I have a couple of tables, one that shows the families and one for the applications of the products. Selecting one of them I want to show all products that belong to the family or that are used in an application.

And here is what I'm struggling with: if I want to show the description and the code of each product in a cell, do I have to perform a query for every product to retrieve their fields or can I use some sort of **"IN" query**? Something like `select * from products where key IN {"-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfa", "-JiGh_31GA20JabpZBfa"}`. I know that it's an SQL like query, but this was just to better explain myself.

Btw, I don't exclude that my way of designing the DB is wrong.

Comment: You will have to load each item separately. Firebase doesn't have an equivalent to a SQL `WHERE id IN (1,2,3)`, not would there be a benefit to having it. For a full explanation, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786

Comment: Hi @FrankvanPuffelen, I have taken a look at your answer. Ok, I'll try to go on with this structure and I'll update my question with my code. Btw, I was at the Dev Summit in Berlin, it was very interesting! ;-)

Comment: Hi again @FrankvanPuffelen, I answered to my own question with your suggestion. Furthermore, I tried to implement a simple project based on that structure.  Can you please take a look at that and, if necessary, give me some advice? I would like to start to integrate Firebase in my projects in the best way.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated in the first comment by @Frank van Puffelen, there is no way to perform a `IN` query or, I suppose, something similar to a `JOIN`.
So here are a few pieces of my code and a brief of the pipeline that I have implemented!

I created 2 `UITableViewController`, the first one to show the *families* and the second one to show the *products* of the selected one.

So, in the first controller I wrote this code to retrieve the **list of families**:

```
let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference()
ref.child("families").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
    if snap.value is NSNull { return }        
    let families = snap.value as! [String:AnyObject]
    for familyKey in families.keys {
        let familyDetails = familyes[familyKey] as! [String:AnyObject]
        self.families.append(FamilyL1.init(familyName: familyKey, familyDetails: familyDetails))
    }
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
```

After the selection of a family, in the second controller I'll perform two queries: one to retrieve **the details of the product** and the other one for the multi-language **description**.

```
for (index, product) in (family?.products ?? []).enumerated() {
    self.ref.child("products").child(product.id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
        if snap.value is NSNull { return }
        product.populateProduct(product: snap.value as!  [String:AnyObject])
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)
    })   
    self.ref.child("it").child("products").child(product.id).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snap in
        if snap.value is NSNull { return }
        product.populateProductDescription(product: snap.value as! [String:AnyObject])
        self.tableView.reloadRows(at: [IndexPath.init(row: index, section: 0)], with: .none)
    })
}
```

As suggested, I've taken advantage of the **parallelism**, so the queries aren't performed sequentially and the interested cells will be refreshed at each update. I've taken care of the **optional values** to achieve that:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath)
    let product = self.family?.products[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = product?.code ?? "..."
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = product?.pDescription ?? "..."
    return cell
}
```

I hope this answer will help those who are trying to use this great platform!